# Struggling with adding links to my mapped array. react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const imagesRowOne = [
  {
    src: [
      "/images/myreadinglist.png",
      "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg",
      "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg",
      "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg"
    ]
  },
  { href: ["https://my-reading-list-and-wishlist.herokuapp.com/"] }
];

const imagesRowTwo = [
  "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg",
  "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg",
  "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg",
  "/images/portfolio placeholder.jpg"
];

const Projects = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={`project-section ${className}`}>
    <div className="projectflex">
      {imagesRowOne.map((img, i) => (
        <a className="projectsrowone" key={i}>
          <img
            className="img-responsive"
            src={img[0][1]}
            href={img[0][2]}
            alt="projectthumbnail"
          />
          {console.log(img)}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
    <div className="projectflex">
      {imagesRowTwo.map((img, i) => (
        <a className="projectsrowtwo" key={i}>
          <img className="img-responsive" src={img} alt="projectthumbnail" />
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
export default Projects;
```

I am struggling here been working on this issue for a few weeks still working on understanding array methods and growing in object operations its my weak point but what I am basically trying to do here is map my images from the src property of my object and then have the links from my href property also be mapped in the exact same order as each image so link index 0 will go with image index 0 what am I doing wrong any help appreicated. I have tried different values to try and work with nested array aspects to no avail as well as trying to call my object properties in my map I am seriously stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new as well so perhaps there are tonnes of ways to improve this answer so please keep that in mind.
This is how i solved this issue;

```
// Extract src and href from imagesRowOne 
const arrayEntries = Object.entries(Object.values(imagesRowOne));
const src = Object.values(arrayEntries[0][1])[0];
const href = Object.values(arrayEntries[1][1])[0];

// populate each image with the href.  
{src.map((img, i) => (
<a className="projectsrowone" key={i}>
  <img
    className="img-responsive"
    src={img}
    href={href[0]}
    alt="projectthumbnail"
  />
  {console.log(img)}
</a>
)
```

ECMA2017 features: Object.values(your-obj) , Object.entries(your-obj)